# Перевод из десятичного числа в двоичное

Tags: c++

Как перевести десятичное число в двоичное и наоборот? Язык C++.

Answer (score 13):

Стандартный способ - использование `std::bitset`.

```
int i = 5;
std::bitset<16> bitset = i;

// 'to_string' вернет строку std::string формата '000...0111'
std::cout << "Binary : " << bitset.to_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,    std::allocator<char> >() << std::endl;
```

---

Обратный способ тоже очевиден:

```
std::bitset<16> bitset("101011");
```

Answer (score 6):

Последовательно записываете остатки от деления на два, потом переворачиваете получившуюся строку.

```
13/2 = 6; 1
6/2 = 3; 0
3/2 = 1; 1
1/2 = 0; 1
```

Ответ: 1101.
Удобнее всего это делать в цикле while.

Обратно - не сложнее.
В цикле for на каждой итерации к ответу прибавляете 2^i (два в степени итератора), если число порядков равно 1 или ничего не прибавляете, если число порядков равно 0. Начинать надо с конца:

1101:

```
i=0: 1 => 2^0 = 1; SUM = 1;
i=1: 0 =>          SUM = 1+0 = 1;
i=2: 1 => 2^2 = 4; SUM = 1+4 = 5;
i=3: 1 => 2^3 = 8; SUM = 5+8 = 13;
```

Comment: А можно выводить справа налево, а потом сдвинуть. Место все равно резервировать надо.

Answer (score 2):

```
void setBinNumber(int Number){

    char tmp;   //0 or 1 for next adding to string binNumber_

    string binNumber_;  //string to return

    while(Number){
        tmp = '0' + Number % 2;
        //cout<<"tmp="<<tmp<<endl;
        binNumber_ = tmp + binNumber_;  //concatenation
        //cout<<"binNumber_="<<binNumber_<<endl;
        Number /= 2;

    }
    cout<<binNumber_;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

из двоичного в десятичное

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number = 0;
    char binary[80];
    int mult = 1;

    cin >> binary;
    for(int i = strlen(binary); i; i--, mult *= 2)
    {
         if(binary[i-1] == '1') number += mult;
         else if(binary[i-1] != '0')
         {
             cout << "error" << endl;
             exit(1);
         }
     }
     cout << number << endl;
     return 0;
```

}

наоборот напишите сами ))

Answer (score 0):

```
void dec2bin(void)
{
    int count, cnt = 0;
    long int inp_numb;
    long unsigned int res;

    cout << " Enter Dec number: ";
    cin >> inp_numb;
    cout << endl;

    for(count = 63;count >= 0; count--)
    {
        res = (long unsigned int)(inp_numb >> count) & 1;
        printf("%llu", res);
        cnt+=1;
        if(cnt == 4)
        {
            printf(" ");
            cnt = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.