# Как перевести число из десятичной системы счисления в двоичную без библиотек

Tags: c++

Нужно написать код который переводит числа из десятичной системы счисления в двоичную. Не используя библиотеки.
Пробовала в массив записывать единицы и нули, но "перевернуть" его не получилось.

Comment: `но "перевернуть" его не получилось` — [`std::reverse()`](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse)?

Comment: Связанный вопрос [Перевод из десятичного числа в двоичное](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/46630/23044)

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте, как это в школе учат: собирайте в цикле остатки от деления на 2, а потом переворачивайте. Это можно и вручную сделать:

`for(int i = 0; i < length / 2; ++i)
{
   swap(bin[i], bin[length - i - 1];
}`

А если принять во внимание, что это программа выполняется на компьютере, где все итак двоичное, то можно упростить и сделать примерно так:

`for(int i = 0; i < max; ++i)
{
    bin[i] = (number & (1 << (max - i - 1)) > 0 ? 1 : 0;
}`

Comment: а что означает `max` в данном контексте ??

Comment: максимальная длина в двоичном представлении. Ее можно определить, например,так: `max = 32; while((number & 1 << max) == 0)--max;`